# FamilyTree not printing descendats and Ancestorsm, just the name of the person. how can I fix that?

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

so I have to print descendants and Ancestor with indentation but when I run my code it only prints the name of the person.

this is my code so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
```

```
public class FamilyTree {

private static final Map<String, Set<String>> relationships = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get route to file "tudor.dat" using classLoader
    String filename = "tudor.dat";
```

```
InputStream inputStream =   FamilyTree.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

```
    // read file
    readFile(inputStream);

    // specify name of the person to look hierarchy
    String personName = "Margaret";

    // find and print ancestor
    System.out.println(personName);
    System.out.println("    Ancestors:");
    findAncestors(personName, 1);

    //find and print descendants
    System.out.println("\n    Descendants:");
    findDescendants(personName, 1);
}

private static void readFile(InputStream inputStream) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split("->");
            if (parts.length == 2) {
                String parent = parts[0].trim();
                String child = parts[1].trim();
                relationships.computeIfAbsent(parent, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(child);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void findAncestors(String person, int indentation) {
    printIndentation(indentation);
    System.out.println(person);

    if (relationships.containsKey(person)) {
        for (String ancestor : relationships.get(person)) {
            findAncestors(ancestor, indentation + 1);
        }
    }
}

private static void findDescendants(String person, int indentation) {
    printIndentation(indentation);
    System.out.println(person);

    if (relationships.containsKey(person)) {
        for (String descendant : relationships.get(person)) {
            findDescendants(descendant, indentation + 1);
        }
    }
}

private static void printIndentation(int indentation) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indentation; i++) {
        System.out.print("    ");
    }
}
```

```
}
```

I had "Familytree\tudor.dat" before and wasn't printing anything then I removed the FamilyTree part and it was just printing the name of the person. like this.

C:\Users\Julim.jdks\openjdk-21.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=52235:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\Julim\IdeaProjects\assigment 4 recursion\out\production\assigment 4 recursion" FamilyTree

Margaret

```
Ancestor:

    Margaret

Descendants:    

    Margaret
```

Process finished with exit code 0

when it should look like this.

Margaret     Ancestors:         Margaret             Elizabeth of York             Henry VII          Descendants:         Margaret             James V                 Mary, Queen of Scots                     James VI & I         Margaret Stuart             Henry, Lord Darnley                 James VI & I

Comment: I suggest formatting your code into a single block, with correct indentation. Thanks.